# Count number of entries in whole SQL Server database

Tags: sql-server

Is there any way I can count the number of all entries in a SQL Server database? Preferably with only one query.

Edit:
The total amount of entries in all tables in a given database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select sum(rows) from sys.partitions;
```

This is a correct answer, for a conveniently definition of 'entry' (chosen by me): a row in a heap or a b-tree.

Answer (score 3):

This query will return a list of all the tables, with an *approximate* row count for each table:

```
SELECT 
    [TableName] = sysobjects.name, 
    [RowCount] = MAX(sysindexes.rows) 
FROM 
    sysobjects, 
    sysindexes 
WHERE 
    (sysobjects.xtype = 'U') AND (sysindexes.id = OBJECT_ID(sysobjects.name))
GROUP BY 
    sysobjects.name 
ORDER BY 
    2 DESC;
```

Comment: This is also very useful for me. Thanks :-)